# Gradle protoc plugin doesn't find default google proto file

Tags: java, android, gradle, protocol-buffers

My proto files use default google protocolbuffers types such as struct and timestamp.

Using the default gradle protoc integration, gradle outputs errors because it can not resolve imports:

> google/protobuf/struct.proto: File not found.
>
> google/protobuf/timestamp.proto: File not found.

Replacing the default gradle protoc block

```
protoc {
    artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.3.0'
}
```

with one specifying where protoc is

```
protoc {
    path = '/usr/local/bin/protoc'
}
```

fixes the issue but it is not portable.

Is there any jar dependency or other portable solution that could make the default gradle protoc definition working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the following dependencies fixes the error:

> compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0'

The dependency provides default google protofiles along the compiled protobuf library.

From Gradle 6+, use `implementation`:

```
dependencies {
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java
  implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.21.10'
}
```

Comment: Yes, this does fix the problem. For reference, the [plugin documentation](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin#protos-in-dependencies) indicates that: `Protos in dependencies (e.g. upstream jars) can be put in either in the compile configuration or the protobuf configuration.`

Comment: Works great, just `compile` has been deprecated and replaced by `implementation`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had everything set up correctly, but IntelliJ didn't auto-import a proto correctly.

I had to change

```
import "struct.proto";
```

to

```
import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";
```